# Unsupported operand type(s) for simple math program

Tags: python

```
city = input("What city are you in?")
print(city + " is a beautiful place")
year = input("How many years have you been living there for?")
current = 2024
move = current - year
print("You moved to" + city + "in the year" + move)
```

Just trying to run a simple program. I wanted it to print something like "You moved to New York in the year 2018"

I am getting an operand error on line 5 with the move variable

Comment: The `input` will return a string.  You need to convert it to an `int`.

Comment: you need to take the time to read error messages, and try to understand what they are telling you. I'll note, you didn't actually post the error message (or the stack trace), which suggests you didn't find the details important. They are, they are very useful, and in this case, are telling you *exactly* what is wrong

Comment: You can't use `+` to combine strings and integers.  Use `,` instead.

Comment: I have read the error message and it is not helping me. So I need to convert to an int for the move variable?

Comment: I figured it out, converted to int and then used the , instead of +   ..thanks guys